# How to check if string matches any of the strings in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to check if string matches any of the strings saved in database, but with the code I have right now it checks only the first one
My code:

```
for (const key in keys) {
  if (keys[key].key !== hashedQueryKey) {
    return "Invalid Key provided.";
  } else return true;
}
```

Comment: You can try something like `var dbStrings = getDatabaseStringsAsArray(); if (dbStrings.includes(theStringIwantToCheck)) { .... do whatever you need .... }`

Comment: remove the else and move "return true" after your for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `return` if the key does not match as you want to continue comparing keys. Something like:

```
function queryMatches(keys, hashedQueryKey) {
 for (const key in keys) {
  if (keys[key].key === hashedQueryKey) {
    return true;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Object.keys and Array.contains() to check if your key is present

```
if (Object.keys(keys).contains(hashedQueryKey)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return "Invalid Key provided.";
}
```

although looking at your code, and being paranoid ... just in case your 'key' property differs from the objects' key, using Object.keys and anyMatch() is safer ...

```
if (Object.keys(keys).anyMatch(key => keys[key].key === hashedQueryKey)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return "Invalid Key provided.";
}
```

if you don't need the message - just true or false , then you can just return the predicate.

ie.

```
return Object.keys(keys).contains(hashedQueryKey);
```